# Storing variable inside of recursive function (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I wrote a recursive function to find (0,0) tuples inside of a list.

```
def find_tuple(l, score = 0):
    for i, item in enumerate(l):
        try:
            if item == 0 and l[i+1] == 0:
                score = score + 1
                print("Number of tuples: {}".format(score))
                l = l[i+2:]
                find_tuple(l, score)
        except:
                break
    return score
```

When I've used it i noticed strange behaviour:

```
>>> find_tuple([0,0])
Number of tuples: 1
1
>>> find_tuple([0,0,0])
Number of tuples: 1
1
>>> find_tuple([0,0,0,0])
Number of tuples: 1
Number of tuples: 2
1

>>> find_tuple([0,0,0,0,0,0])
Number of tuples: 1
Number of tuples: 2
Number of tuples: 3
Number of tuples: 2
2
```

The function returned 1 instead of 2 and 2 instead of 3 in the last two examples. Why is this happening ?

Comment: As your own output shows, the code is calculating the values right, you need to use the returned value

Comment: Do you search for consecutive zeros? For example, the result of [0,2,3,0] is 0, and the result of [0,0,0,1,0,] is 2.

Comment: OP here, sorry for the misunderstanding - I meant to find unique tuples (0,0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return the variable for the previous function call to catch it.

replace  `find_tuple(l, score)` with `return find_tuple(l, score)` inside the `if` statement

```
def find_tuple(l, score = 0):
    for i, item in enumerate(l):
        try:
            if item == 0 and l[i+1] == 0:
                score = score + 1
                print("Number of tuples: {}".format(score))
                l = l[i+2:]
                return find_tuple(l, score)
        except:
                break
    return score
```

Comment: Thanks. One keyword "return" could have ruined my day :D

Answer (score 0):

Your recursion logic doesn't seem correct to me. You don't need to use for loop in a recursive function. You handle a part of job, reduce the problem and call the same function again to rest of the problem. At the end, use the returned value from the function. Also, you need to put a condition to stop.

Something like this could work for your problem:

```
def find_tuple(l, score = 0):
    if len(l)<=1:
        return score

    if l[0] == 0 and l[1] == 0:
        score += 1

    return find_tuple(l[2:], score)


print(find_tuple([0,0]))
print(find_tuple([0,0,0]))
print(find_tuple([0,0,0,0]))
print(find_tuple([0,0,0,0,0,0]))
```

Output:

```
1
1
2
3
```

Comment: The logic is correct, you need to return the values directly instead of saving it in `score` variable. At first i also thought logic is wrong, but it isnt. :)

Comment: If OP needs to find consecutive tuple number, then your logic is right. If OP expects tuples to have unique `0` in each tuple, then the OP's logic is right

Comment: OK. If he wants to print all of the steps, the logic is correct. But using for loop in every function call does not seems correct to me.

Comment: I do agree, that for loop inside every function call can be expensive

Comment: Doesn't `if item == 0 and l[i+1] == 0` mean consecutive? It controls (i)th item and (i+1)th item.

Comment: Yes, but the examples show that, expected is unique 0,0 tuples

Comment: Thanks. I guess, I fixed it with a little change.

Comment: OP here, sorry for the misunderstanding - I meant to find unique tuples.